# check if email already exists

Tags: symfony, unique-constraint

I'm using the class UniqueEntity to validate when email has already used to add new user. This work fine when I add a new user, but when I try to login with a user putting email and password return error saying that this email already exists. If I remove UniqueEntity the login work fine.

My code:

```
namespace Demo\DBBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;
}


public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $action = $this->generateUrl('login');
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user, array('action' => $action));

    $form->handleRequest($request)

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $this->redirect();
    } else {
        return $this->render('FrontBundle:User:login.html.twig', array(
            'login' => $form->createView(),
            'error' => true
        ));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your login form and controller ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use validation groups to include Unique validation only on registration phase.

See here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-validation-groups